# layout with footer menu and and colorful border around

Tags: android, layout, menu, border

i'm trying to create a layout who has a footer menu and a border for all around of activity,
the layout i want is like this link:
http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-07/77256228248741098308.png
1.yellow:border like,
2.black:content(text),
3.purple:footer menu who repeat in all activities,
4.red:image view,

is framelayout useful in this case?

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="69dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp" >
  </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I don't know your particular situation, but a consisting footer bar is not something you generally see in Android apps (as appose to IOS) and is at most times not recommended, I really advice you to read the [Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html) if you haven't done so already.

Anyways, a RelativeLayout or perhaps LinearLayout with some weight attributes is probably a better suit than FrameLayout. But if you want the footer to stay put across all activities, you should learn about [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead.

With LinearLayout you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:paddingRight="32dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#F1EF16"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#FA263F">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3D3C11"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
            ...
         </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:background="#F800F6">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```